# How to make an Axes transparent to events?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to find a way to make an `Axes` object passthrough for events.

For context, I have a figure with 6 small subplots. Each of them responds to mouse motion events by displaying a cursor dot and text info where the user aims. I also made it so that clicking a subplot will make it as large as the figure  for better visibility. When moving the mouse over invisible axes, `event.inaxes` will still point to that ax despite being set to invisible and that is what I would like to avoid.

Below is the MRE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.set_gid("ax1")
ax2.set_gid("ax2")
fig.show()

def on_movement(event):
    """Write on the figure in which `Axes`object the event happened."""

    width, height = fig.bbox.bounds[2:]
    x = event.x/width
    y = event.y/height
    text = ax.get_gid() if (ax := event.inaxes) is not None else "None"
    fig.texts[:] = []
    fig.text(x, y, s=text, transform=fig.transFigure, c="white", bbox=dict(fc="#0055AA", ec="black"))
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", on_movement)
```

As expected, as you hover the mouse over `ax1`, the empty gap and `ax2`, you will see one of those three texts appear:
[image]

```
ax1.set_position((1/3, 1/3, 2/3, 2/3))
```

Same thing as I arbitrarily resize and move `ax1` so that it is partly overlaps with `ax2`.

[image]

```
ax2.set_visible(False)
```

Now this is my problem. Invisible axes still trigger events. **Is there a way to make some axes "transparent" to events?** Obviously the usual technique of sorting all the cases in the callback does not work here.

[image]

Currently envisaged solutions:

- ideally, finding a setting akin to `zorder` so that the "highest" axes gets the event.
- ugly workaround: set the position of the invisible axes to `((0, 0, 1e-10, 1e-10))`.
- less ugly: working with figure coordinates to convert `event.x`, `event.y` into `event.xdata`, `event.ydata` for the only ax that I know is visible. Basically `xdata1, ydata1 = ax1.transAxes.inverted().transform((event.x, event.y))` if `event.inaxes` is not None + see if there are edge cases.

The latter is already implemented and does work, so save your time if you want to write a reply using that approach. I'm mostly interested in an amazing one-liner that I would have missed, something like `ax2.set_silenced(True)`.

Python 3.8.5
Matplotlib 3.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, setting the appropriate `zorder` does work actually.

```
ax1.set_zorder(2)
ax2.set_zorder(1)
...

def on_movement(event):
    ...
    fig.text(x, y, ..., zorder=1000)
    ...
```

[image]